# Subsurf challenge

Tags: modeling

I understand why this problem exists. But now, how do I fix it? This is a very simple representation of a very much more complicated mesh I have, but this is my simplest explanation of my problem. It is a subdivided surface formula in my mesh, but now I want to break it so I can have a piece out of my pie. But not when that means my pie changes its rounded curve. Please, some pointers...

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you need to apply the subsurf modifier and then remove the slice

Comment: But that would leave me with an insane amount of vertices, right? Isn't there a better solution? I need animation as well, so I'm not looking forward to this compute activity...

Comment: SubSurf will not work on Vertex groups, So you will have to find another way. The vertex count should not need to be too high if you are using smooth shading.